# Error when calling API by entering tryout tab in publisher UI

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I register the API with the publisher, go to the tryout tab, generate a key, and then verify it, but an error appears as shown below. What part did I set wrong? I need help.

Log file
[2021-10-06 13:50:07,068] ERROR - InternalAPIKeyAuthenticator Invalid Internal Key.XXXXXUlMyNTYifQ
[2021-10-06 13:50:07,069]  WARN - APIAuthenticationHandler API authentication failure due to Invalid Credentials

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPfQW.png

Comment: looks like an invalid access token

Comment: @pubic, I regenerated the key every time I called the API. Still, the same error persists. How can I keep a valid key?

Comment: What is the APIM version? After creating and publishing the  API from publisher portal, in the store/devportal did you tried to generate the client key and secret or did you try to generate the API key?

Comment: Hi Saranki,   APIM version is 4.0.0.   and after creating and publishing the API from publisher, I called the API from the publisher UI. Because in publisher, API developer can try out without subscription. The image I attached is not a devportal, but a tryout function in publisher.

Comment: Have you made any changes to the Keystore and Truststore of the API Manager? Especially to the `gateway_certificate_alias` public certs in the trust-store?